# list files modified in last 2 weeks

Tags: python, time

I would like to return all the files in a directory specified by the user that have been modified in the last 2 weeks. I am a bit new to python and I am not quite sure how to do that. Here is what I have so far. Thanks for any help.

```
import os, time

def modFiles():
    file_list=[]
    directory=input("Please enter where you would like to check for modified files.")
    Two_weeks= 1209600
    for files in directory:
        mtime=os.path.getmtime(directory)
        if mtime < Two_weeks:
            file_list.append(files)
        print(file_list)
```

It gives the output:

```
Please enter where you would like to check for modified files./home/student/Desktop
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be calling `os.path.getmtime(files)` insteaad of `os.path.getmtime(directory)`. Also right now directory is a string since that is what `input` returns so you're looping over the characters in the string. You should be doing `for files in os.listdir(directory)`